# Erlang process dies after disconnect

Tags: erlang, distributed

I got the following setup:

- 2 Servers with fqdn usa.local and gca.local
- 1 erlang node on each of them named alice@usa.local and bob@gca.local

When I start Alice (`alice:start/0`) on alice@usa.local it spawns linked Bob (`bob:start/1`) on gca.local. Both processing are trapping exits.

When Alice dies of something, Bob gets notified and keeps on running.
When Bob dies of something, Alice gets notified and keeps on running.

When I cut the network connection, Alice gets notified that Bob has died of `noconnection` and process bob dies on bob@gca.local.

I do not want this to happen. I want Bob to keep on running although it looses connection to Alice.

**My questions are:**

- Has this something to do that I initially spawn Bob from the Alice node?
- How can I make Bob to survive a connection loss?

---

Here goes the code:

```
-module (alice).
-compile (export_all).

start () ->
    register (alice, spawn (fun init/0) ).

stop () ->
    whereis (alice) ! stop.

init () ->
    process_flag (trap_exit, true),
    Bob = spawn_link ('bob@gca.local', bob, start, [self () ] ),
    loop (Bob).

loop (Bob) ->
    receive
        stop -> ok;
        {'EXIT', Bob, Reason} ->
            io:format ("Bob died of ~p.~n", [Reason] ),
            loop (Bob);
        Msg ->
            io:format ("Alice received ~p.~n", [Msg] ),
            loop (Bob)
    end.
```

---

```
-module (bob).
-compile (export_all).

start (Alice) ->
    process_flag (trap_exit, true),
    register (bob, self () ),
    loop (Alice).

loop (Alice) ->
    receive
        stop -> ok;
        {'EXIT', Alice, Reason} ->
            io:format ("Alice died of ~p.~n", [Reason] ),
            loop (Alice);
        Msg ->
            io:format ("Bob received ~p.~n", [Msg] ),
            loop (Alice)
    after 5000 ->
        Alice ! "Hi, this Bob",
        loop (Alice)
    end.
```

Comment: That is not very idiomatic erlang...

Comment: @Dustin Thank you for your comment. Do you have an answer to my questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `io:format/2` call on line 13 of bob.erl. When new process is created in `spawn_link('bob@gca.local',...` it inherit the group leader of `alice` process which is a process local to `alice@usa.local` so you will see all output from `bob` on `alice@usa.local` terminal. When `alice@usa.local` is disconnected `bob` handles `EXIT` message on line 12 of `bob.erl` but `io:format/2` call on line 13 is failed because group leader was disconnected.

The quick fix is to change all bob's `io:format/2` calls to `io:format(user, Format, Data)`. In this case all bob's output will be displayed on `bob@gca.local` terminal.

However in real projects you really should use [gen_server](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html) behavior because it handles many rough cases, especially for inter-node communication (don't forget to look at the code). Moreover you really need to use [monitor/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2) or/and [monitor_node/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor_node-2) instead of `link` and `trap_exit` here.

Comment: Great answer. Gimme some time to verify it before I accept. What is advantage of monitor (one-way) if I want the processes to watch one another mutually?

Comment: Links are really for the case when you want all linked processes will terminate in case of a error. And only special processes should set `trap_exit` flag (don't forget that files, sockets, ports, etc. also create links to the current process). But if you only want to receive a message in case if other process is terminated you should to use monitors. Just setup two monitors to each other process and you get the current behavior without links and `trap_exit`.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I see a `trap_exit` in code, I assume someone's reinventing some part of OTP.  That seems to be the case here.

Take a look the [distributed applications](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/distributed_applications.html) documentation.  This does what you want in just configuration.

I've used it with pretty good amounts of success for about 7 years now (currently between an atom box and an arm5 box).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but do you actually have some answers to my questions?